# Showing an inequality is valid

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Suppose that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive real numbers and that $a \leq b + c$. By
cross multiplying or otherwise, show that

$$\frac{a}{1 + a} \leq \frac{b}{1 + b} + \frac{c}{1 + c}$$

Anyone able to get this to work out? I cross multiplied them but am unable to manipulate it into an expression that verifies the statement.

Answer (score 1):

By cross multipliying since $a,b>0$
\begin{equation}a(1+b)(1+c)\le b(1+a)(1+c)+c(1+a)(1+b)\Leftrightarrow a+ab+ac+abc\le b+ba+bc+bac+c+ca+cb+cab\Leftrightarrow a\le b+c+2bc+abc
\end{equation}
which holds since $a\le b+c$ and $a,b,c>0$