# Inequality. Further solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, fractions

For the community of inequalities.

If $z\leq x+y$  ,And  $x, y, z \neq -1$, prove :

$$
\frac{z}{1+z} \leq \frac{x}{1+x} + \frac{y}{1+y}.
 $$

I have this proof, but I feel there should be other simpler (direct) proofs

My attempt:

$$
z(1-z+z^2-\dots)\leq (x+y)(1-z+z^2-\dots),
$$

now the idea is that either $(1-z+z^2-\dots)\leq(1-x+x^2-\dots)$ and $(1-z+z^2-\dots)\leq(1-y+y^2-\dots)$ are true, and thus

$$
z(1-z+z^2-\dots)\leq x(1-x+x^2-\dots)+y(1-y+y^2-\dots),
$$

which is exactly

$$
\frac{z}{1+z}\leq\frac{x}{1+x} + \frac{y}{1+y}
$$.

**Note:** I have added the above condition for $x,y,z$ to  define The LHS and RHS of inequality

Comment: I believe $x,y,z \ge 0$ also

Comment: Yep, fogot to mention

Comment: Your attempt is nonsense. Says who that $1/(1+2) = 1-2+4-8+...$???

Comment: A counter-example is $z=-2, x=y=1$. – For non-negative numbers there are already *many* solutions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/250086/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/672881/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1110391/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1717384/42969 and more ...

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $-1< a\leq b$ then $${a\over 1+a}\leq {b\over 1+b}$$ and $$ {x\over 1+x+y} \leq {x\over 1+x}$$

Comment: What about a=b=-1 or x=y=-1 ?

Comment: The inequality is *wrong* unless you restrict it to non-negative $x,y,z$ – and then it is a duplicate of many other Q&As.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(t) = \frac{t}{1+t}$ is strictly increasing:

$$f'(t) = \frac{1}{(1+t)^2} > 0$$

Therefore, if we assume $x, y, z \ge 0$ and $z \le x + y$ then

$$\frac{z}{1+z} = f(z) \le f(x + y) = \frac{x+y}{1+x+y} = \frac{x}{1+x+y} 
 + \frac{y}{1+x+y} \le \frac{x}{1+x} + \frac{y}{1+y}$$

Answer (score 2):

$x,y,z \geq 0$  so $0 \leq xy(2+z) $ and $z \leq x+y $, add these
\begin{eqnarray*}
z &\leq& x+y+2xy+xyz \\
\color{blue}{zx+zy+zxy}+z &\leq& x+y+2xy+xyz +\color{blue}{zx+zy+zxy}\\
z(1+x)(1+y) &\leq& \underbrace{(x+y+2xy)}_{x(1+y)+y(1+x)}(1+z) \\
\frac{z}{1+z} &\leq& \frac{x}{1+x} +\frac{y}{1+y}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

For positives $x$ and $y$ we obtain:
$$\frac{x}{1+x}+\frac{y}{1+y}>\frac{x}{1+x+y}+\frac{y}{1+x+y}=\frac{x+y}{1+x+y}=$$
$$=1-\frac{1}{1+x+y}\geq1-\frac{1}{1+z}=\frac{z}{1+z}.$$

Comment: For “positives” this is a duplicate of *many* Q&As, you also provided an answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2299636/42969.

Comment: I did not knew about. I marked it like a duplicate.

Comment: Just in case you did not know about it: There is this great search engine https://approach0.xyz/ (announced at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24978/42969). Just type a latex math expression into the search field.  In this case: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7Bz%7D%7B1%2Bz%7D%20%5Cleq%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B1%2Bx%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7By%7D%7B1%2By%7D%24&p=1 immediately returns 12 hits.

Comment: @Martin R It was your down voting?

Comment: No – what makes you think that?